# Using a dummy control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to dynamically generate controls in a Panel but the controls are pretty complex and I want to use an already existing control and duplicate it inside the Panel.

I have tried using the XamlWriter method:

```
string saved = XamlWriter.Save(booksWindow.DummyBook);
StringReader sReader = new StringReader(saved);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
Grid newgrid = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
newgrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //initial control is Collapsed
booksWindow.BooksWrapper.Children.Add(newgrid);
return true;
```

This causes the new control to also be named after the initial control which, as I understood, might pose some problems later on. Is that true? And if so, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid controls having the same Name property should not be a problem. From [Names in XAML for XamlReader.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name(VS.95).aspx):

> You can specify a Name or x:Name on elements that are part of the input for Load. However, any such name created will be in a discrete XAML namescope, which extends only to the root in the XAML input provided. If you call Load and subsequently add the created objects to the main object tree , this consideration will affect how you call FindName, and from what object scope you should call it.

Basically what this means is that you can't use the Name property to locate the Grid controls for bindings or other purposes which doesn't look like something you will need to do.

Comment: The Panel contains multiple grids, each holding info about a book. The application must be able to edit contents for each grid separately. How could I do that?